# fork system call failed with eperm operation not permitted

Tags: unix, fork

I am running a shell script which in turn is calling lot of system commands. 
The command is returning an error:

> cannot fork - try again.

This is the strace:

```
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 15
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(15, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 16
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(16, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(16, 1)                             = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
fork()                                  = 23067
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
dup2(15, 0+ id
)                             = 0
close(15)                               = 0
close(16)                               = 0
dup2(14, 1)                             = 1
close(14)                               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
fork()                                  = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
kill(23067, SIGKILL)                    = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

The output from the ulimit command is:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515646
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 1024
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 32656
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the necessary authorization to fork.

Comment: I guess this is on Linux, given the strace format. But `fork` isn't a commonly used system call on modern Linux (glibc uses the more general `clone` instead) and `EPERM` isn't a standard error for `fork`. What kind of system are you running on (what distribution? what libc?) and what exact kernel version? Have any patches been applied, especially security-related patches?

Comment: Hi Giles, I am using glic 2.12 and RH Linux 6.5.

Comment: Hi Giles, uname -r 's output is 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: anti virus had policy (bit9) not fork,